# route table issue when I appended option net.ifnames=0 to grub2

Tags: linux, routing, linux-networking, ethernet, rhel7

I appended two options `net.ifnames=0` `biosdevname=0` to `grub2` because I want to change default network name to old name `eth0` on **RHEL 7**.

After that, I edited `/etc/sysconfig/network` to set default gateway for machine:

`GATEWAY=192.168.88.1`

And configured network interface. When I have only one network interface `eth0`, everything works well.

Here is the route table with one network interface `eth0`:

```
[root@devmachine ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
[root@devmachine ~]#
```

But I got the issue with route table, when more than one network interface online.

```
[root@devmachine ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
172.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth1
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth1
[root@devmachine ~]#
```

As you can see, gateway address `192.168.88.1` was added to `eth1` at the last line. And the gateway address is appended continuously with new network interface.

```
[root@devmachine network-scripts]# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
default         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 eth1
default         192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         UG    102    0        0 eth2
172.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     100    0        0 eth1
172.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     101    0        0 eth2
192.168.88.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eth0
192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth1
192.168.88.1    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    101    0        0 eth2
```

Actually, the issue appears only when i appended the option `net.ifnames=0` to `grub2`. Someone help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add

```
DEFROUTE=no
```

To all the interfaces that should **not** have the default route. In your case, adding `DEFROUTE=no` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` should do the trick.

Alternatively, instead of setting `GATEWAY` in `/etc/sysconfig/network` you can set it in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0` instead. I.e.

```
echo 0.0.0.0/0 via 192.168.88.1 > /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-eth0
```

You can refer to the [RHEL 7 Network Guide](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Networking_Guide/sec-Using_the_Command_Line_Interface.html#sec-Static-Routes_and_the_Default_Gateway)

By the way, I believe your problem has nothing to do with what you did with the grub configuration.

Comment: hi chutz thanks for your help, change `DEFROUTE=no` and everything are normal now.